# How to start the server with ES6 standards

Tags: node.js

I have a server, the code of the file index.js is shown below. I want to post it on https://dashboard.heroku.com/. But it does not start the command `node inde.js`.

```
import http from 'http'
import express from 'express'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';


const port = process.env.PORT || 8081;
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.status(200).send({
    message: 'Welcome',
}));

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at ${port}`);
});
```

How to run it using the ES6 standard, command `node inde.js`? I have installed `babel7`

Comment: The question isn't specific enough. What does *it does not start the command* mean? Node already supports ES6 for a long time. The thing you likely refer to are *ES Modules*.

Comment: My code does not start with the command `node inde.js`. Gives an error message `import http from 'http'
       ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`. How to run my code with the command `node inde.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ES6 import is not yet fully supported by Node. It is still experimental. To use them, you need to change your files extension from `.js` to `.mjs` and start them with this flag :

```
node --experimental-modules my-app.mjs
```

More details there : https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html