# Unexpected token import express js

Tags: node.js, express

Below is my project location on the GitHub:

https://github.com/nandy2013/MERN-Stack-Dev

I am just trying to import the method from the js file on another js file with below implementation:

**is-empty.js**

```
const isEmpty = value =>
value === undefined ||
value === NULL ||
(typeof value === 'object' && Object.keys(vale).length === 0) ||
(typeof value === 'string' && value.trim().length === 0);

module.exports = isEmpty;
```

**register.js**

```
//code
import isEmpty from './is-empty';
//code
```

**Snippet:**

[image]
I am getting below error message

> C:\Users\1217688\Desktop\devconnector\validation\register.js:2 import
>   isEmpty from './is-empty'; ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
>       at new Script (vm.js:51:7)
>       at createScript (vm.js:138:10)
>       at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:199:10)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:624:28)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)

Any help please!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start the server with ES6 standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54649936/how-to-start-the-server-with-es6-standards)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, node.js does not support ECMAScript's `import` statements, so instead of writing `import isEmpty from './is-empty';` you should write `const isEmpty = require('./is-empty');`.

If you prefer to use `import` statements, you can enable ECMAScript Modules support by adding `--experimental-modules` argument to Node. But please be aware that their support is still experimental and it is not recommended to use them in production environments. In your case, you'll need to edit the `package.json` file of your project and replace `start` script command to:

```
node --experimental-modules ./server.js
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped me!

Answer (score 0):

The latest versions of node.js supports ES6. So you can export your function directly and import it.

```js
const isEmpty = value => {
  value === undefined ||
    value === NULL ||
    (typeof value === 'object' && Object.keys(vale).length === 0) ||
    (typeof value === 'string' && value.trim().length === 0);
}

export default isEmpty;
```

And in your other file you can import as "import isEmpty from './isEmpty'". If you are exporting just one function, use default export.