# Error when deploying ES6 Node Js to Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, babeljs

I have an express server with graphql and react as front end. I am using babel-node to run my server.js and using webpack to bundle my modules. I wanted to deploy my app using Heroku and I've read that babel-node is not recommended for production and that I should use a transpiler to convert ES6 to ES5. I went ahead and did some researches online and found a way to convert all my server files to ES6 using babel.

**my scripts**

[image: a busy cat]

This basically creates a folder called 'build' and transpiles all my server files in it. It works when I type **yarn start**

I also have my front end connected to the server so that they use the same port.

[image: a busy cat]

**Procfile**

```
web: node build/server.js
```

so basically, I have 2 additional folders created for Heroku.

```
/build
/dist
```

One is for my server files and the other one is for react.

When I run them locally `http://localhost:5000` everything runs fine. But when I push to heroku, I get these errors.

[image: a busy cat]

It looks like it is not reading my transpiled files and I don't know what's going on. It looks fine to me.

When I open the heroku app it says **Application error** and when it shows an error in console.

[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 0):

This is because:

1. currently for pure ES6 to work you have to start node with "--experimental-modules"
2. your files must be renamed from .js to .mjs
3. check the node version supports ES6

Are you sure your Babel step is transpiling correctly?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/all.html#esm_enabling

As per points 1~2/3

Comment: ...and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54649936/how-to-start-the-server-with-es6-standards

Comment: After playing around with it for a while, It finally worked. I did not have to do the steps you mentioned. I think it's my Procfile, it didn't log anything to the console. I guess the path was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have you install express yet? You can try this:

```
npm install express
```

Comment: If you look at the log output you'll see that "import" is an unexpected identifier. Node in this case doesn't know what to do with "import"